# Will my command-line utility be able to store data in its own directory?

Tags: windows, file-permissions

My go CLI app uses a directory to hold themes and other read-only data in a subdirectory of the app itself. On first invocation the app creates that subdirectory from data embedded in the .EXE. So if the app gets copied to `%LocalAppData%\Programs\MyApp`, it creates and populates the subdirectory  `%LocalAppData%\Programs\MyApp\.mydata`.

When you create a new project using my app, it creates a directory in user data space, and copies that .mydata subdirectory into your project.

Is that a feasible technique? Will I run into permissions trying to write to `%LocalAppData%\Programs\MyApp\.mydata`, for example? Sorry but I'm working on a Mac and do not know the new Windows ways.

Comment: the question isn't whether the app can write to the directory, the question is can the user the app is executing on behalf of can write to the directory. presuming the user has permissions to copy the application to their profile appdata directory, then that user will by default have access to let programs write to that directory. generally speaking content within the users profile directory is writable by the user.

Comment: I have seen the error of my ways and will indeed put the data in the profile appdata directory. Thanks much.