# Should I instruct people using my command-line utility to install to %LocalAppData%\Programs?

Tags: windows

I'm writing a command-line app in Go and would like to release to Windows, Mac, and Linux. It's a single .EXE (which I hope will be able to write into its own home directory, a question asked in [Will my command-line utility be able to store data in its own directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/1759992/will-my-command-line-utility-be-able-to-store-data-in-its-own-directory)). Audience is tech writers and devs who may be new to whatever platform they're running it on.

I'll be including directions on adding it to the path. Is the convention to suggest that they copy it to `%LocalAppData%\Programs`?

And a bonus question. Is it acceptable to ask them to use cmd.exe to perform this process, and to reach it by typing into the Windows search bar? Seems like entering `cmd` is the easiest way to get the job done even though it's not used as much anymore. I just want the easiest and most universal way go explain how to do it.

Comment: first, you really should be writing an installer package instead of considering how best to instruct the user on installation if your app requires modifying environment or the registery. as for the path, that is fine, as long as the user doesn't need to be admin to run it successfully. if the app needs admin, you are probably better off storing it outside the users profile. it is important that if you add the exe to the path, and it is in the users profile directory, that it be added to the USERS path variable, not the system PATH.

Comment: Thank you. It won't modify the environment. I just want to copy it to a place where I know the user has access. And admittedly I am loathe to create an installer for a single .EXE. Since I'm not a Windows expert anymore I'm afraid that I might cause more problems if I do so... your thoughts on that? It's a free utility and I hope to revisit that issue after the first release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered you don't actually need to care where your executable is running from in order to be writing to a working/config directory? I'd consider having a sensible default and also giving the user a switch/param to use another directory passed as an arg.

Further you should consider actually using %appdata% instead of %localappdata% as it would help with roaming profiles.

Comment: Thanks. I will switch to %appdata%. And Go lets me just embed the config in the executable, so you're right!